# "Государства — члены Евразийского экономического союза". Ставить тире или дефис?

Tags: пунктуация, приложение, дефис-тире

> «Итоги взаимной торговли товарами государств — членов Евразийского
>   экономического союза за 2015-2016 годы».

Что нужно в предложении — тире или дефис? Правильное ли здесь согласование между словами?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Корректное написание предложения:

> «Итоги взаимной торговли государств **—** членов Евразийского экономического союза за 2015**–**2016 годы».

***Почему:***

1. Сочетание «торговля товарами» избыточно. Слово «торговля» уже подразумевает деятельность по обороту, купле и продаже **товаров**.
2. В случае если приложение (то есть часть предложения *членов Евразийского экономического союза*) неоднословно, дефис заменяется на тире.

   [Источник](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%B8_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F/#id-4%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%C2%A7154): **Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации.** Полный академический справочник / Под ред. В.В. Лопатина. — М.: Эксмо, 2006. — 480 с.
3. Для обозначения числовых диапазонов (2015–2016) используется короткое (среднее) тире.

   Подробнее: https://www.artlebedev.ru/kovodstvo/sections/97/.